# How can i get $_POST full value without any sanitization operation on it in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a controller something like this in codeigniter:

```
class ABC extends MX_Controller {
  ...
  ...
  ...
   .
   .
   .
  ...
  ...

  public function getTestPostData(){
    print_r($_POST);
  }
}
```

In `getTestPostData` when i print `$_POST` i need full `$_POST` data without any sanitization of any kind. I can't set `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;` in `config.php`

How can i achieve that?

**Edit:**

In post data i am sending some HTML content with some `<script>`(script) tags, but when i print the data in my controller using `$this->input->post("content")` the `<script>`(script)tags gets replace by [removed] tags. This happens when the global_xss_filtering is TRUE. I can't change this value to FALSE.

I hope now the question is clear.

Comment: hmm, i didn't know that Codeigniter modified $_POST

Comment: can you give us the output of `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: @Shvelo, thats because `xss` protection is on ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, in my tests it worked even after unsetting `$_POST` completely.

```
public function getTestPostData()
{
    $post_data = explode( "&", file_get_contents('php://input') );
    $result = array();

    foreach( $post_data as $post_datum ) {
        $pair = explode("=", $post_datum );

        $result[urldecode($pair[0])] = urldecode($pair[1]);
    }

    print_r( $result );
}
```

Comment: file_get_contents reads the content from file, here i am talking about form post.

Comment: @Elvis It reads contents from `"php://input"`, I.E. anything sent in the request body. On a lower level PHP does it too and creates the initial `$_POST` array for you. ....Please look at http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown

Comment: in that case, i'll definitely try it.

Comment: ooh WOW it worked, learnt a new thing today :) Thanks Esailija

Comment: @Elvis considering accepting the answer if it works for you. :P

Answer (score 0):

you can't set $config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE; in config.php?

then if  you can't access core/input.php class
and remove _POST from it

```
function _sanitize_globals()
{
    // It would be "wrong" to unset any of these GLOBALS.
    $protected = array('_SERVER', '_GET', '_POST', '_FILES', '_REQUEST', 
                        '_SESSION', '_ENV', 'GLOBALS',
```

or change the var $xss_clean to false like this

```
    function get_post($index = '', $xss_clean = FALSE)
{
    if ( ! isset($_POST[$index]) )
    {
        return $this->get($index, false); //here
    }
```

then you can't view the post data unfiltered from

```
 print_r($_POST);
print_r( $this->input->post() )
```

that's all

Comment: I know what you have just posted here, i need a way around

Answer (score 0):

If you have CI v. 2+ try the following:

Create a new Core file that extends CI_Security and overwrite the `xss_clean` function like so:

```
class MY_Security extends CI_Security {

    public function xss_clean($str, $is_image = FALSE)
    {
      return $str;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I just tested this and it works. FYI.